# How to get every entity between two locations

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

```
VMPlugin plugin = VMPlugin.getPlugin(VMPlugin.class);
Location target = p.getTargetBlock(null, 5).getLocation();
World world = target.getWorld();
Location ploc = p.getLocation();
Entity[] entities = //Entities between ploc and target (edit : straight line and everything up to 0.25 blocks away from it)
```

I tried Vector, but I don't know how to use it well.

Also if it is possible I would like to get only the first entity (If the EntityArray will work i will use just entities[0]).

Comment: That would heavily depend on your definition of "between". A straight line would probably yield no entity 99.9% of the time.
In any case, there are commands e.g to get all entities in a radius of a specific location. I'd assume there are other command that take different restrictions, you'll have to google them yourselves though.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to get the closest entity to the player?

Comment: Unfortunately after your edit, this still is not clear. What about the height that should be considered? Entity Positions are just points, but they are rendered in three dimensions with an x, y and z-Size. Should the position of the entity be in a "tube" with 0.25 blocks as radius?